# How to mock a PaginatedScanList in DynamoDB?

Tags: mocking, mockito

I know it's a bad thing to mock a list, instead of mock the item in list. But PaginatedScanList is too hard to new the instance. It's construct is too many params, and I try to new this list, then I find it's unmodifiable list, so that we can't add item to it.

How can I create a simple List to return in UT?

Answer (score 1):

Now, I use the mock(PaginatedScanList.class) and mock the method:

```
when(scanList.toArray()).thenReturn(new Array[....])
```